# NFS on ReadyNAS: mount fails

Tags: mount, nfs

I get this error message when trying to mount an exported NFS folder from a ReadyNAS:

```
root@computer:/home/tom# mount -t nfs 192.168.188.210:/TRANSFER /NAS/Transfer -vvvv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Sep 12 10:26:47 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.188.210,clientaddr=192.168.188.18'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.188.210,clientaddr=192.168.188.18'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.188.210,clientaddr=192.168.188.18'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.188.210'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.188.210 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.188.210 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 58886
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

I did not change anything on the server side but set up a new client. This is why I am sure the problem must be on the client.

Thanks in advance.